# Can't find items in a 2-D array

Tags: java, arrays, eclipse, substring, multidimensional-array

I am trying to make a program where the user inputs the first part of a postcode, either 3 or 4 characters (i know it can be two but i can add that in later) and the program goes through a 2-D array and outputs all values that correlate to it. I thought that my logic was sound in getting a substring of the postcode in the two dimensional array (which is formed from a csv document read into it in an earlier section of code). I get a series of errors in the console and I have no idea what is going wrong. Just wanted to post on here to see if anyone could help me with this. Below is the code for the method responsible for carrying this process out:

```
public void PostCodeSearch(){
    ReadingFromAFile();
    String StrPstCd = PstCd.getText();
    for (int x = 0; x < twod.length; x++) {
        if (StrPstCd.length() == 3){
            String PstCdSub = twod[x][3].substring(0,2);
            if (StrPstCd.equals(PstCdSub)) {
                text.append("Price = " + twod[x][1] + " " + "Date of Sale: " + twod[x][2] + " " + "Postcode: " + twod[x][3] + "\n");
            }
        }else if(StrPstCd.length() == 4){
            String PstCdSub = twod[x][3].substring(0,3);
            if(StrPstCd.equals(PstCdSub)){
                text.append("Price = " + twod[x][1] + " " + "Date of Sale: " + twod[x][2] + " " + "Postcode: " + twod[x][3] + "\n");
            }// end if
        }

    }// end for
}
```

Comment: what are the errors from the console?

Comment: Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: 3
 at java.lang.String.substring(Unknown Source)
 at ExampleGUI.PostCodeSearch(ExampleGUI.java:117)
 at ExampleGUI.actionPerformed(ExampleGUI.java:76)
 at java.awt.Button.processActionEvent(Unknown Source)
 at java.awt.Button.processEvent(Unknown Source)
 at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
 at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
 at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
 at java.awt.EventQueue.access$200(Unknown Source)

Comment: at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
 at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
 at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
 at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
 at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
 at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)
 at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)
 at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
 at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)

Comment: at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
 at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source)
 at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
 at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown Source)
 at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
 at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
 at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source)

Comment: Thanks, it's easier to edit the initial post next time rather than post in comments. The important part to look at is the 

`Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: 3` 

which is telling us it is trying to access a String at character '3' but the String doesn't have that many characters.

Comment: `text.append("Price = " + twod[x][1] + " " + "Date of Sale: " + twod[x][2] + " " + "Postcode: " + twod[x][3] + "\n");` You may be meaning to say `twod[x][0]`, `twod[x][1]`, `twod[x][2]` as well as having only a max of 2 in the second spot of the array elsewhere as well

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Best guess without seeing the rest of your code.
Assumes that twod is a 2d String array, with d0 being the sale array index, d1 being of the imaginary enum {UNKNOWN, PRICE, DATE, POSTNUMBER}.

```
public void PostCodeSearch() {
    ReadingFromAFile();
    String StrPstCd = PstCd.getText();

    for (int i = 0; i < twod.length; i++) {
        for (int x = 0; x < twod[i][3].length; x++) {

            if (StrPstCd.length == 3  && twod[i][3].length <= x + 3) {
                String PstCdSub = twod[i][3].substring(x, x + 3);
                if (StrPstCd.equals(PstCdSub)) {
                    text.append("Price = " + twod[i][1] + " " + "Date of Sale: " + twod[i][2] + " " + "Postcode: " + twod[i][3] + "\n");
                }
            } 

            else if(StrPstCd.length == 4 && twod[i][3].length <= x + 4) {
                String PstCdSub = twod[i][3].substring(x, x + 4);
                if (StrPstCd.equals(PstCdSub)) {
                    text.append("Price = " + twod[i][1] + " " + "Date of Sale: " + twod[i][2] + " " + "Postcode: " + twod[i][3] + "\n");
                }
            }

        }
    }
}
```

You didn't check if you where trying to compare StrPstCd with a substring out of the bounds of twod[i][3]... and just mixed up string indices and twod unit indicies a bit all around

Should actually be something like

```
import static java.util.regex.*;

public void PostCodeSearch() {
    ReadingFromAFile();
    String StrPstCd = PstCd.getText();
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("^\\S*" + StrPstCd + "\\S*$");
    for(int i = 0; i<twod.length; ++i) {
        Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(twod[i][3]);
        if (matcher.matches()) {
            text.append("Price = " + twod[i][1] + " " + "Date of Sale: " + twod[i][2] + " " + "Postcode: " + twod[i][3] + "\n");
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: I'm off of my computer for the night now, so I'll try this in the morning and let you know how I get on :)